# What is the difference between a Person and an Employee in Kronos?

Tags: terminology, kronos-workforce-central

According to the [*Kronos Workforce Central 6.3 Developer's Reference Guide*](https://community.kronos.com/s/article/Workforce-Timekeeper-v6-3-Developer-s-Toolkit-Reference-Guide), one of the required properties when running a `<HyperFindQuery>` is `QueryPersonOrEmployee`.

> #### RunQuery
>
> Returns a list of people and associated information for the specified
>   HyperFind query.
>
> Return Value Type: Zero or more HyperFindResult tags
>
> Required Properties: HyperFindQueryName, VisibilityCode,
>   QueryDateSpan, QueryPersonOrEmployee

The Action Descriptions section states that the possible values for `QueryPersonOrEmployee` are *Person*, *Employee*, and *Job Assignment*.

> #### QueryPersonOrEmployee 
>  Category (person, employee, job assignment) for query
>
> The type of person being requested in the query
>
> Type: String
>
> Optional
>
> Enumerated value: Person, Employee, Job Assignment

As far as I can tell, this is the only part of the API which makes any distinction between a *Person* and an *Employee*. I was under the assumption that both terms were interchangeable in Kronos.

***What is the difference between a Person and an Employee in Kronos Workforce Central?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone is a person but not everyone is an employee. Employee's have an employee license while if a person simply has a manager/web license then they are not an employee.